# How to swap values (array, int) in nodes? - C language

Tags: c, struct, swap

I'd like to swap values in these two nodes - especially `char name[30]` . I used `strcpy`, but it shows me: "*overlapping memory*".

```
typedef struct node {
    char name[30];
    int points;
} LISTnode;


    int main() {


        LISTnode *p, *t;
        p = (LISTnode*)malloc(sizeof(LISTnode));
        t = (LISTnode*)malloc(sizeof(LISTnode));

        p->points = 30;
        t->points = 20;
        strcpy( p->name, "Peter" );
        strcpy( t->name, "Thomas" );



        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: where in your code is it showing the memory overlapping? there is no output at all

Comment: `LISTnode temp; temp = *p; *p = *t; *t = temp;`

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc`

Comment: strcpy takes both argument as char pointer,

Answer (score 0):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
    char name[30];
    int points;
} LISTnode;

void swap( LISTnode *a, LISTnode *b )
{
    LISTnode tmp = *a;

    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    LISTnode *p, *t;
    p = (LISTnode*)malloc(sizeof(LISTnode));
    t = (LISTnode*)malloc(sizeof(LISTnode));

    p->points = 30;
    t->points = 20;
    strcpy( p->name, "Peter" );
    strcpy( t->name, "Thomas" );

    printf( "*p = { %d, %s }\n", p->points, p->name );
    printf( "*t = { %d, %s }\n", t->points, t->name );

    putchar( '\n' );

    swap( p, t );

    printf( "*p = { %d, %s }\n", p->points, p->name );
    printf( "*t = { %d, %s }\n", t->points, t->name );

    free( p );
    free( t );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
*p = { 30, Peter }
*t = { 20, Thomas }

*p = { 20, Thomas }
*t = { 30, Peter }
```

Comment: but whats the reason for memory overlap?

Comment: @TanujYadav I am sorry I have not understood your question.

Comment: in the question OP said that " I used strcpy, but it shows me - overlapping memory.", Whats the reason for that?

Comment: @TanujYadav Ask this question to OP. He did not showed the relevant code demonstrating this problem. On the other hand his general question is "How to swap values (array, int) in nodes? - C language"